# Enviar email com anexos em PHP

Tags: php, html, envio-de-email, email

Estou a enviar um email, funciona tudo bem. Agora queria adicionar alguns ficheiros como anexo. Tenho o seguinte código:

```
$from = $_SESSION['email_cliente'];
$email_destino = "teste@teste.com";
$subject = "Assunto";
$messagem = "Isto é uma mensagem enviada por php"
$headers = "From: $from <$from>\r\n".
           "MIME-Version: 1.0" . "\r\n" .
           "Content-type: text/html; charset=UTF-8" . "\r\n"; 
mail($email_destino, $subject,$message,$headers);
```

Como lhe posso adicionar anexos?

Comment: Acredito que seja melhor vc utilizar o PHPMailer ou outra biblioteca para enviar emails com anexo pois é mais simples que utilizar a função mail().

Comment: Talvez isso ajude http://wiki.locaweb.com.br/pt-br/Enviando_e-mails_com_anexo_em_PHP

Answer (score 21, accepted):

**Usando a funcão `mail()`**

Um email é composto de um cabeçalho e um corpo, sendo que o corpo pode ser separado em várias partes. No padrão o termo usado para identificar o separador destas partes é `boundary`. Sendo assim vamos definir um `boundary` para nosso email. As regras para gerar um `boundary` pode ser encontrado na [internet facilmente](http://tools.ietf.org/pdf/rfc2046.pdf). Mas simplificando, nada mais é que uma string aleatória que deve aparecer no email apenas quando for para indicar uma parte do email.

```
$boundary = "XYZ-".md5(date("dmYis"))."-ZYX";
```

Obtenha as informações do arquivo que vai anexar

```
// Arquivo enviado via formulário
$path = $_FILES['attachment']['tmp_name']; 
$fileType = $_FILES['attachment']['type']; 
$fileName = $_FILES['attachment']['name']; 

// Ou arquivo local
$path = '/caminho/para/o/arquivo';
$fileType = mime_content_type( $path );
$fileName = basename( $path );

// Pegando o conteúdo do arquivo
$fp = fopen( $path, "rb" ); // abre o arquivo enviado
$anexo = fread( $fp, filesize( $path ) ); // calcula o tamanho
$anexo = chunk_split(base64_encode( $anexo )); // codifica o anexo em base 64
fclose( $fp ); // fecha o arquivo
```

Definindo o cabeçalho (Existe outras informação importantes de cabeçalho que você pode adicionar para evitar que o email caia na caixa de SPAM).

```
// cabeçalho do email
$headers = "MIME-Version: 1.0" . PHP_EOL;
$headers .= "Content-Type: multipart/mixed; ";
$headers .= "boundary=" . $boundary . PHP_EOL;
$headers .= "$boundary" . PHP_EOL;
```

Definição da mensagem em HTML

```
$mensagem  = "--$boundary" . PHP_EOL;
$mensagem .= "Content-Type: text/html; charset='utf-8'" . PHP_EOL;
$mensagem .= "Mensagem"; // Adicione aqui sua mensagem
$mensagem .= "--$boundary" . PHP_EOL;
```

Anexando um arquivo

```
$mensagem .= "Content-Type: ". $fileType ."; name=\"". $fileName . "\"" . PHP_EOL;
$mensagem .= "Content-Transfer-Encoding: base64" . PHP_EOL;
$mensagem .= "Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=\"". $fileName . "\"" . PHP_EOL;
$mensagem .= "$anexo" . PHP_EOL;
$mensagem .= "--$boundary" . PHP_EOL;
```

Enviando o email

```
mail($para, $assunto, $mensagem, $headers);
```

**Usando o PHPMailer**

Faça download do [PHPMailer](http://github.com/PHPMailer/PHPMailer) e extraia os arquivos na pasta de seu projeto.

Inclua o arquivo principal do PHPMailer

```
require_once('caminho/para/o/phpmailer/class.phpmailer.php');
```

Preparando o email

```
$email = new PHPMailer();
$email->From      = 'nome@exemplo.com';
$email->FromName  = 'Seu nome';
$email->Subject   = 'Assunto';
$email->Body      = 'Corpo do email';
$email->AddAddress( 'destinatario@exemplo.com' );
```

Anexando o arquivo

```
$file_to_attach = 'caminho/do/arquivo/para/anexo';
$email->AddAttachment( $file_to_attach , 'nome_do_arquivo.pdf' );
```

Enviando o email

```
$email->Send();
```

O PHPMailer reduz várias linhas de código para um simples comando `$email->AddAttachment();`, bem mais simples! Usando o PHP puro será várias linhas a mais e provavelmente encontrará várias dificuldades e bugs.

Comment: Usando a função mail(), quando eu quero enviar o ficheiro, ele não vem de nenhum formulário. Estou a ir buscar o nome do ficheiro à BD e pode haver a possibilidade de enviar mais que um ficheiro como anexo. Como posso contornar esta questão?

Comment: Ou mesmo usando o PHPMailer, como lhe posso adicionar vários anexos? obrigado

Comment: Para enviar vários arquivos basta obter um array com os caminhos de arquivos e realizar um loop executando os trechos de anexo de arquivo para cada caminho.Para obter o caminho do arquivo via BD basta usar o que falo de obter informações de arquivos locais. Se estiver como BLOB recomendo guardar as informações para envio como nome, tamanho e tipo junto ao registro.

Comment: Fiz do jeito do `mail()`, porém só está indo o anexo, o conteúdo da mensagem em si não é enviado o que pode estar ocorrendo? @marcusagm

Comment: O segundo limite é concatenado com a linha de cima. E por isso ele nao exige o HTML. Basta inserir esse no lugar do segundo:  ** $mensagem .= "\n--$boundary" . PHP_EOL;  ** Basta inserir o  "\n" pra dar uma quebra de linha e mostrar tanto o HTML quanto o anexo