# Enviar mail com anexo

Tags: php

Quero enviar um mail, ao clicar num butão ou hyperlink com um anexo. O ficheiro encontrar se no diretório onde está a página. Estou a utilizar este codigo [Enviar email com anexos em php](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/11417/enviar-email-com-anexos-em-php)

Dá um erro dizendo que não conhece function mime_content_type(). Quero utilizar sem formulários.

```
$boundary = "XYZ-".md5(date("dmYis"))."-ZYX";

$path = '/teste.txt';
$fileType = mime_content_type( $path );
$fileName = basename( $path );

// Pegando o conteúdo do arquivo
$fp = fopen( $path, "rb" ); // abre o arquivo enviado
$anexo = fread( $fp, filesize( $path ) ); // calcula o tamanho
$anexo = chunk_split(base64_encode( $anexo )); // codifica o anexo em base 64
fclose( $fp ); // fecha o arquivo

// cabeçalho do email
$headers = "MIME-Version: 1.0" . PHP_EOL;
$headers .= "Content-Type: multipart/mixed; ";
$headers .= "boundary=" . $boundary . PHP_EOL;
$headers .= "$boundary" . PHP_EOL;

$mensagem .= "Content-Type: ". $fileType ."; name=\"". $fileName . "\"" . PHP_EOL;
$mensagem .= "Content-Transfer-Encoding: base64" . PHP_EOL;
$mensagem .= "Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=\"". $fileName . "\"" . PHP_EOL;
$mensagem .= "$anexo" . PHP_EOL;
$mensagem .= "--$boundary" . PHP_EOL;

$para="teste@teste.com";
$assunto="teste";

mail($para, $assunto, $mensagem, $headers);
```

Comment: A função equivalente a [mime_content_type()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mime-content-type.php) é [finfo](http://php.net/manual/en/function.finfo-file.php)

Comment: Dá o mesmo erro. So quero que o anexo seja anexado, tipo o <a href=mailto:teste@teste.com>email</a> em que abre o software de mail.

Comment: Você quer que o anexo vire o corpo do email com formatação html?

Comment: Não, que apareça em anexo para depois o utilizador inserir o assunto e a mensagem no software de mail.

Answer (score 2):

A função [`mime_content_type()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mime-content-type.php) já é obsoleta.
Como disse o usuário @perdeu, deve-se hoje usar [`finfo()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.finfo-file.php), que cumpre a mesma funcionalidade de um jeito melhor. Você pode adicionar no início do seu *script* a seguinte função, como visto nessa [questão](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1263957/why-is-mime-content-type-deprecated-in-php):

```
function _mime_content_type($filename) {
    $result = new finfo();
    if (is_resource($result) === true) {
        return $result->file($filename, FILEINFO_MIME_TYPE);
    }
    return false;
}
```

E então substitua em seu *script*:

```
$fileType = mime_content_type( $path );
```

por

```
$fileType = _mime_content_type( $path );
```

Comment: Da-me o seguinte erro Class 'finfo' not found

Comment: Esse erro diz que o PHP não encontrou a Classe finfo. Qual a versão do seu PHP e qual seu sistema operacional? A partir 5.3 o PHP já vem com finfo, mas se você usa Windows, precisa habilitá-lo no arquivo php.ini, descomentando a linha que contém extension=php_fileinfo.dll e reiniciando o Apache após isso.