# PHP anexo / Anexo codificado

Tags: php, phpmailer

Estou tentando enviar um anexo em php pela função mail, com um código que peguei em um site, porém não está funcionando.

Quando envio a mensagem ela chega certinho, porém, so que era pra ser anexo chega codificado

```
<?php

    foreach ($_POST as $key => $value) {
        $$key = $value;
    }

        $arquivo = $_FILES["arquivo"];
        $boundary = "XYZ-".date("dmYis")."-ZYX";
        $fp = fopen($arquivo["tmp_name"], "rb"); // abre o arquivo enviado
        $anexo = fread($fp, filesize($arquivo["tmp_name"])); // calcula o tamanho
        $anexo = base64_encode($anexo); // codifica o anexo em base 64
        fclose($fp); // fecha o arquivo 


        $headers  = 'MIME-Version: 1.0' . "\r\n";
        $headers .= 'Content-type: text/html; charset=iso-8859-1' . "\r\n";
        $headers .= 'From: Termo de adesão - Pine Tree Farm <mail@meuemail.com.br>' . "\r\n";
        $headers .= 'To: Termo de adesão - Pine Tree Farm <mail@meuemail.com.br>' . "\r\n";

        $mensagem ='<html>
        <head>
        <title>Termo de adesão - Pine Tree Farm</title>
        </head>
        <body>
        <p style="color:#412D0A; font-size:16px">Termo de adesão: <b>'.$nome_crianca.'</b></p>
        <div style=
        "
            border: 1px solid #eee;
            width: 90%;
            padding: 10px;
            font-size: 14px;
        "
        >
            <p style="font-size: 14px; padding: 8px; background-color: #4D9EA8; color: #FFFFFF;">Dados da Criança</p>
                <p><strong style="color: #412D0A">Nome: </strong>'.$nome_crianca.'<p>
                <p><strong style="color: #412D0A">Data de Nascimento: </strong>'.$data_nascimento.'<p>
                <p><strong style="color: #412D0A">Sexo: </strong>'.$sexo.'<p>                

            <p style="font-size: 14px; padding: 8px; background-color: #4D9EA8; color: #FFFFFF;">Datas e programação escolhida</p>
                <p><strong style="color: #412D0A">Datas: </strong>'.$data_1.' '.$data_2.' '.$data_3.'<p>
                <p><strong style="color: #412D0A">Programação Escolhida: </strong>'.$optradio.'</p>

            <p style="font-size: 14px; padding: 8px; background-color: #4D9EA8; color: #FFFFFF;">Dados do Responsáveis</p>
                <p><strong style="color: #412D0A">Nome: </strong>'.$nome_responsavel.'<p>
                <p><strong style="color: #412D0A">Telefones: </strong>'.$telefones.'<p>
                <p><strong style="color: #412D0A">E-mail: </strong>'.$email.'<p>
                <p><strong style="color: #412D0A">Nome: </strong>'.$nome_responsavel2.'<p>              
                <p><strong style="color: #412D0A">Telefones: </strong>'.$telefones2.'<p>                
                <p><strong style="color: #412D0A">E-mail: </strong>'.$email2.'<p>

            <p style="font-size: 14px; padding: 8px; background-color: #4D9EA8; color: #FFFFFF;">Ficha Médica da Criança</p>
                <p><strong style="color: #412D0A">Toma algum medicamento regularmente? </strong>'.$medicamento.'<p>
                <p><strong style="color: #412D0A">Quais? </strong>'.$medicamento_quais.'<p>
                <p><strong style="color: #412D0A">Qual periodicidade? </strong>'.$remedio_periodicidade.'<p>
                <p><strong style="color: #412D0A">Qual periodicidade? </strong>'.$medicamento_periodicidade.'<p>
                <p><strong style="color: #412D0A">A enfermeira está autorizada a administrar o medicamento? </strong>'.$administrar_medicamento.' <br><br>Receita e medicamento deverão ser entregues em mãos pelos pais à enfermeira.<p>
                <p><strong style="color: #412D0A">Tem alguma alergia ou restrição? </strong>'.$alergia_restricao.'<p>
                <p><strong style="color: #412D0A">Recomendações: </strong>'.$alergia_restricao_recomendacoes.'<p>
                <p><strong style="color: #412D0A">Em caso de emergência encaminhar para qual hospital: </strong>'.$emergencia_hospital.'<p>
                <p><strong style="color: #412D0A">Contato do médico responsável: </strong>'.$contato_pediatra.'<p>
                <p><strong style="color: #412D0A">Telefone: </strong>'.$telefone_pediatra.'<p>
                <p><strong style="color: #412D0A">Possui plano de saúde? </strong>'.$plano_saude.'<p>
                <p><strong style="color: #412D0A">Qual: </strong>'.$qual_plano.'<p>
                <p><strong style="color: #412D0A">Número: </strong>'.$numero_plano.'<p>
                <p><strong style="color: #412D0A">Recomendações: </strong>'.$recomendacoes2.'<p>

             <p style="font-size: 14px; padding: 8px; background-color: #4D9EA8; color: #FFFFFF;">Ficha de atividades da Criança</p>
                <p><strong style="color: #412D0A">Tem alguma restrição a alguma atividade física? </strong>'.$atividade_fisica.'<p>
                <p><strong style="color: #412D0A">Quais: </strong>'.$atividade_fisica_quais.'<p>
                <p><strong style="color: #412D0A">Recomendações: </strong>'.$recomendacoes3.'<p>

            <p style="font-size: 14px; padding: 8px; background-color: #4D9EA8; color: #FFFFFF;">Equitação</p>
                <p><style="color: #412D0A">
                    Nesta edição da Colônia de Férias Pine Tree Farm, contamos com a parceria da Escola de Equitação do Jardim Botânico.  Com mais de 20 anos de experiência no ensino e na condução de atividades hípicas infantis na Escola de Equitação da Hípica de Brasília (www.escoladahipica.com.br), os profissionais da Escola de Equitação conduzirão atividades pedagógicas e recreativas com segurança, utilizando os Equipamentos de Proteção Individual cabíveis.<br><br>

                    Os cavalos e éguas que estarão conosco são dóceis e estão acostumados a trabalhar com crianças.<br><br>

                    As aulas serão conduzidas, de acordo com as possibilidades de cada criança, pelo professor João sob a direção do cavaleiro José Cabral de Araújo Neto.<br><br>
                <p>
                <p><strong style="color: #412D0A">A criança está autorizada a realizar as atividades de equitação: </strong>'.$equitacao.'<p>

            <p style="font-size: 14px; padding: 8px; background-color: #4D9EA8; color: #FFFFFF;">Recreação na Piscina</p>
                <p><style="color: #412D0A">
                    A Pine Tree Farm possui uma piscina cercada com tela de segurança cujas portas de acesso permanecerão trancadas durante a Colônia de Férias.  O nível de água da piscina será reduzido para menos de um metro de profundidade.<br><br>

                    Com os prováveis baixos teores de umidade relativa do ar e altas temperaturas nas horas mais quentes do dia, as crianças com 6 ou mais anos de idade terão atividades recreativas na piscina as quais serão conduzidas por profissionais treinados e com experiência nas melhores escolas de natação de Brasília.<br><br>
                <p>
                <p><strong style="color: #412D0A">A criança está autorizada a realizar as atividades na piscina? </strong>'.$recreacao_piscina.'<p>

            <p style="font-size: 14px; padding: 8px; background-color: #4D9EA8; color: #FFFFFF;">Imagens</p>
                <p><style="color: #412D0A">
                    A colônia contará com fotógrafo profissional para registro de suas atividades, bem como para realização de fotos das crianças que poderão ser adquiridas pelos pais. Parte das imagens será disponibilizada no site da colônia. Os interessados também poderão visualizar todas as fotografias na recepção da colônia.<br><br>

                    Os pais autorizam a utilização das imagens das crianças no grupo de whatsapp, no site e nas redes sociais da Colônia de Férias Pine Tree Farm.<br><br>               

                    Na eventualidade dos responsáveis desejarem que alguma foto seja retirada, bastará que uma mensagem seja enviada por e-mail especificando a imagem para que a mesma seja excluída destes canais de comunicação.  As imagens somente serão utilizadas em material impresso após autorização por escrito dos responsáveis previamente contatados pela Pine Tree Farm.
                <p>

            <br><br>
            <p style="text-align: center;">_______________________________________________<br>Mãe ou responsável</p>
            <p style="text-align: center;">_______________________________________________<br>Pai ou responsável</p><br>
            <p style="text-align: center;"> Brasília ________de____________de 2017 </p>
            </div>
        </body>
        </html>
        ';

        $mensagem .= "Content-Type: ".$arquivo["type"]."; name=".$arquivo['name']."";
        $mensagem .= "Content-Transfer-Encoding:base64";
        $mensagem .= "Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=".$arquivo['name']."";
        $mensagem .= "$anexo \n";
        $mensagem .= "--$boundary \n";



        if (mail($to, $subject, $mensagem, $headers)){

                    echo "<script> alert('Enviado com sucesso!')</script>";
                    //echo "<script> history.back()</script>";
                    exit();         
                    }
                    else{
                        echo "<script> alert('Não foi possivel cadastrar!')</script>";
                        echo "<script> history.back()</script>";
                        exit();
                        }
                        return true;                        
?>
```

Comment: Como assim "codificado"

Comment: Aparece assim no final do email: Content-Type: application/pdf; name=61 Ideias de Vendas e Marketing.pdfContent-Transfer-Encoding:base64Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=61 Ideias de Vendas e Marketing.pdfJVBERi0xLjINCiXi48/TDQoxIDAgb2JqDQo8PA0KL0NyZWF0aW9uRGF0ZSAoRDoxOTEwMjAxMTExMDA5MDEpDQovUHJvZHVjZXIgKFwzNzZcMzc3XDAwMEFcMDAwY1wwMDByXDAwMG9cMDAwYlwwMDBhXDAwMHRcMDAwIFwwMDBEXDAwMGlcMDAwc1wwMDB0XDAwMGlcMDAwbFwwMDBsXDAwMGVcMDAwclwwMDAgXDAwMDNcMDAwLlwwMDAwXDAwMDFcMDAwIFwwMDBmXDAwMG9cMDAwclwwMDAgXDAwMFdcMDAwaVwwMDBuXDAwMGRcMDAwb1wwMDB3XDAwMHMpDQovU3ViamVjdCAoRXN0dWRvIDEpDQovS2V5d29yZHMgKCk

Comment: relacionada  https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/11417/enviar-email-com-anexos-em-php?rq=1

Comment: Deu certo não :(