# Php - enviar e-mail!

Tags: php, email, phpmailer, envio-de-email

Gostaria de incluir o `$nome` e `$email` no corpo da mensagem, mas não estou conseguindo.

```
<?php
    // recebe as Variaveis
$nome = $_POST[“nome”];
$email = $_POST[“email”];
$emailDonatario = $_POST[“emailDonatario”];
$mensagem = $_POST[“mensagem”];

//Inclui o arquivo class.phpmailer.php localizado na pasta phpmailer
include(“class.phpmailer.php”);

// Inicia a classe PHPMailer
$mail = new PHPMailer();

// Define os dados do servidor e tipo de conexão
$mail->IsSMTP();
$mail->Host = “smtp-mail.outlook.com”; // SMTP server example
$mail->Port = 587;
$mail->SMTPSecure = ‘tls’;
$mail->SMTPAuth = true; // Usa autenticação SMTP? (opcional)
$mail->Username = ‘MEUEMAIL@outlook.com’; // Usuário do servidor SMTP
$mail->Password = ‘*********’; // Senha do servidor SMTP

// Define o remetente.
$mail->From = "MEUEMAIL@outlook.com"; // Seu e-mail
$mail->FromName = “Samuel”; // Seu nome

// Define os destinatário(s)
$mail->AddAddress($email, $nome);
$mail->AddCC(‘MEUEMAIL@outlook.com’, ‘Eu’); // Copia
$mail->AddBCC($emailDonatario, $nome); // Cópia Oculta

// Define os dados técnicos da Mensagem
$mail->IsHTML(true); // Define que o e-mail será enviado como HTML

// Define a mensagem (Texto e Assunto)
$mail->Subject = “Mensagem do site”; // Assunto da mensagem
$mail->Body = $mensagem,’$nome’;

// Envia o e-mail
$enviado = $mail->Send();

// Exibe uma mensagem de resultado
if ($enviado) {
echo “E-mail enviado com sucesso!”;

} else {
echo “Não foi possível enviar o e-mail !”;
}
```

Comment: Possível duplicata de [Enviar email com anexos em php](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/11417/enviar-email-com-anexos-em-php)

Comment: **1)** Todas as aspas do seu código estão erradas, o que gerará erro de sintaxe se não corrigí-las; **2)** Você utilizou vírgula em uma possível tentativa de concatenar os valores em `$mail->Body = $mensagem,’$nome’`; **3)** Você inseriu uma variável em uma *string* sem motivo em `’$nome’`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Não ficou claro qual erro você esta tomando, mas um dos problemas que identifiquei com relação ao conteúdo da mensagem "$mail->Body = $mensagem,’$nome’;" você esta colocando as variáveis $mensagem e $nome mas não está concatenando.
Acredito que o correto seria:

```
$mail->Body = $mensagem . $nome;
```

Comment: Muito bom, era isso mesmo, muito obrigado!